# C# Why can I not programmatically kill a console program started in Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, kill-process, taskscheduler

I have a console program to run a daily batch.  I have a UI that I can use to alter parameters in a db that the console program uses.

I thought it would be great to be able to stop and start this program from the UI and I can do that.

However, I have the console program set to start before the work day using Task Scheduler in case the machine should be rebooted - at least I know the program will be running when the day starts.

However, I cannot kill it when it has been started by Task Scheduler.  Get "Access is denied".

Why?  And how can I solve this?

Comment: Execute with admin rights?

Comment: Can you kill the process manually from the `Task Manager`? Is still such message appeared?

Comment: Yeah - can kill it using task manager.  No problem.

Comment: Did you run your program by `Run as administrator`?

Comment: Is a clickonce app - cannot be run as administrator?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running, what code are you using to kill the process, and are you using a different account to start the process in Task Scheduler than the account you are using to kill the process?

Comment: In Windows OS; Find your executable file of the program which kill the wanted process, for run that, right-click on it then choose `Run as administrator`.

Comment: @Matt  Windows 10 - pretty much the same code as posted by Siyavash below.  Same account (my account) for both.

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to kill it more than once?  The only reason you might get "Access Denied", based on the scenario you describe, is trying to Kill the process after it has already begun shutting down (see note at end of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hmm. I do have a loop as per code below. Wiĺl de-loop it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following method:

```
private void KillProcessByProcessName(string strProcessName)
{
    foreach (Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(strProcessName))
        p.Kill();
}
```

e.g:

```
private void btnProcessKiller_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KillProcessByProcessName("winword");
}
```

Comment: That is what I am using.  Works fine if I manually start the process to be killed, but won't kill the exact same process if I start it using Task Scheduler.